# WiFi card HardBlocked on HP Pavilion dv6

Tags: wireless, hp, intel, dv6

I'm running into some issues getting my WiFi card to work on my HP Pavilion dv6.

Product Number: A3E82AV

I thought it was the card, originally I had a RALINK RT5390 which wasn't working. I then ordered an INTEL Centrino Advanced-N 6235 AGN in hopes to get this working but no luck.

rfkill list all only has 1 entry showing:
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft Blocked: no
        Hard Blocked: yes

I tried numerous things and have not been able to figure this one out. Does anybody have any ideas?

Pressing F12 does not work. The light is red, stays red and i'm not getting much response from the button.

Thank you!

Comment: You might try pressing your fn key simultaneously when you press f12 or you may have an f-lock key or function. You can also check your BIOS settings to see if the card is disabled in the BIOS settings and you can usually check your f key settings in your BIOS as well.

Answer (score 0):

Wow... It just started working. Not sure why though which is a little concerning...

What I did: 
- Reset BIOS settings to default.
- Restarted 3 times
-> after 3rd reboot it started to work

Makes no sense to me but I'll take it.

I additionally downloaded and "installed" the driver (cp into /lib/firmware).
Also disabled the network manager power settings by setting it from 3 to 2.
And lastly set software & update settings to include Canonical Partners & Canonical Partners (Source Code).

Again, not sure why it now works but yayy. 
@mchid - Thank you!!

Thank you everyone else that looked at this

-Dungeon4